# CSS Lexical Error

Tags: css, wordpress, syntax-error, lexical

I was having trouble with how an image is displaying and so I ran it through the W3C CSS validator and I received this code. I tried to search around for what it might mean but couldn't find much help. I found some people saying that it might be because of special characters in the CSS so I checked that in notepad ++ and didn't find anything.

> 2840 #whoweare img
>
> > Lexical error at line 2838, column 10. Encountered: " " (32), after : "#" post-9 #whoweare { width:100%; }

```
# post-9 #whoweare {
    width:100%;
}
```

Line 2840 is the last one.

Any ideas what this might be?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `#` and `post-9` you have a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) between them.

```
#post-9 #whoweare {
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: And I feel like a total idiot. Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that.